# Fluent Nhibernate Many-to-Many mapping with extra column, update

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, mapping, many-to-many

Can not update / insert data into the database
This is the tables I have:

Role (Id, Name, ...)

Privilege (Id, Name, ...)

RolePrivilege (Id, RoleId, PrivilegeId, IsAllowed)

I have map:

```
public class RoleWithPrivilegesEntityMap : ClassMap<RoleWithPrivilegesEntity>
{
        public RoleWithPrivilegesEntityMap()
        {
            Table( "ROLE" );
            Not.LazyLoad();
            Id( x => x.Id, "ID" ).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map( x => x.Name, "NAME" ).Not.Nullable().Length( 100 );
            HasMany(x => x.RolePrivileges)
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
                .Inverse()
                .Fetch.Join().KeyColumn("RoleId");
        }
}

public class PrivilegeEntityMap : ClassMap<PrivilegeEntity>
{
    public PrivilegeEntityMap()
    {
        Table("PRIVILEGE");
        Id(x => x.Id, "ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Name, "NAME").Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.RolePrivileges)
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Inverse()
            .Fetch.Join().KeyColumn("PrivilegeId");
    }
}

public class RolePrivilegeEntityMap : ClassMap<RolePrivilegeEntity>
{
        public RolePrivilegeEntityMap()
        {
            Table("ROLEPRIVILEGE");
            Id(x => x.Id, "R_ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.IsAllowed, "ISALLOWED").Not.Nullable();
            References(x => x.Role)
                .Not.Nullable()
                .Column("R_ID");
            References(x => x.Privilege)
                .Not.Nullable()
                .Column("P_ID");
        }
}
```

I'm trying to update existing record

```
session.SaveOrUpdate(rolePrivilege)
```

database make insert into table RolePrivilege, but I need to at first delete record.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

normally nothing will go to the database at all because you never call `session.Flush()` or `transaction.Commit()`. However with Id generation Identity you basicly force NHibernate to insert immediately hence you see the INSERT statement.

You can also get rid of the Id in `RolePrivilegeEntity` and form a compositeId over Role and Priviledge which would also enhance performance (no need to insert immediatly).